# string_split function

Tags: sql

How can I convert a textual string like

```
(A-12-AB), (P-13-PQ),(N-14-NM)
```

into a table with 3 columns like:

```
A   12   AB
P   13   PQ
N   14   NM
```

Comment: The solution would depend on the `(R)DBMS` you are using, please add a Tag to your question like for example `postgresql` OR `db2` OR `oracle` OR `sql-server`, OR whatever DBMS you are using

Comment: To clarify the solution-space: (a) Where does the input string come from? Depending on the amount of such strings, and the format (text-file, etc.) an import-utility or data-loader program may be of use. (b) Any programming language or tool you could use for your database/SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle can you use this query:

```
 MYTABLE

 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 FIELD1                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 FIELD2                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 FIELD1                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)

WITH INPUT AS ( 
               select 'A-12-AB' as string_input from dual union 
               select 'P-13-PQ' as string_input from dual union 
               select 'N-14-NM' as string_input from dual
              )
insert into MYTABLE
select regexp_substr(input.string_input, '[^-]+', 1, 1) as field1,
       regexp_substr(input.string_input, '[^-]+', 1, 2) as field2,
       regexp_substr(input.string_input, '[^-]+', 1, 3) as field3
  from INPUT;
```

Thank you